# Why does git show a file is modified when there are no changes in the diff view?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-2019

I am using git with VS 2019 and I frequently end up in a situation where git shows a file as being modified but when I compare with previous the diff view shows no changes.

When I click on "Undo changes", nothing happens, the file stays in the modified state. I thought maybe the file was being auto-edited so I tried closing document's window before undoing the change but that didn't work either. I also suspected that this might be related to eol changes but I confirmed in VS that line-endings are CRLF and match my gitattributes.

[image]

```
*.csproj    text eol=crlf
*.sln       text eol=crlf
*.cs        text eol=crlf
*.json      text eol=crlf
*.config    text eol=crlf
*.xml       text eol=crlf

[core]
    autocrlf    true
```

The only thing I can do in these situations is commit the changes anyways which mucks up the history with unmodified files or blow away the repo and re-clone it. A hard reset doesn't do anything either.

Comment: If a file's permission is changed, for example from `644` to `755`, it's also modified.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your files have already been staged, and are ready for commit.

In this case, the easiest way to see the diffs in these files is with the '--cached' option, like this:

```
git diff --cached
```

or

```
git diff --cached <file_name>
```